# Python - Negative numbers not adding, but positive numbers do

Tags: python-3.x

I am supposed to add up the rows and the grand total of all the numbers. I can add the grand total well, but I am unable to add the row that has negative numbers only. The following code adds up the positive numbers but do not add up the negative numbers correctly.

```
grandTotal = 0
sumRow = 0

for x in range(len(numbers)): 
  sumRow = (sumRow + x)
  print(sumRow)

for x in range(len(numbers)):
  for y in range(len(numbers[x])):
    grandTotal = grandTotal + int(numbers[x][y])

print(grandTotal)
```

When the user input is:

```
1,1,-2 -1,-2,-3 1,1,1
```

My output is: 0
1
3
-3

instead of: 0
-6
3
-3

I know it has something to do with the first for loop, but I can't figure it out. When I try this:

```
grandTotal = 0
sumRow = 0

for x in range(len(numbers)): 
  sumRow = (sumRow + (numbers[x]))
  print(sumRow)

for x in range(len(numbers)):
  for y in range(len(numbers[x])):
    grandTotal = grandTotal + int(numbers[x][y])

print(grandTotal)
```

I get the error message:

```
File "list.py", line 14, in 
sumRow = (sumRow + (numbers[x]))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

Why doesn't my code add up the negative numbers? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is `numbers`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you say

```
sumRow = (sumRow + (numbers[x]))
```

To add integers you say 1+1, not (1+(1)) this would be adding to lists so you could change that.
From my understanding numbers is an array as well, so saying

```
numbers[x]
```

Will give you many numbers. What you want is the total for every row,  and the total of all rows. Heres a program that does this. I am assuming that your program automatically gets numbers from the user input.

```
grandTotal = 0
for row in numbers:
    #for each row we find total amount
    rowTotl = 0
    for value in row:
        #for each column/ value we add tot the row total
        rowTotl += value
    print(rowTotl)
    #add this row's value to the grandTotal before we move on
    grandTotal += rowTotl
#After all adding we print grand total
print(grandTotal)
```

The reason your program doesn't add negative numbers, is really because the row totals are not adding numbers at all. They are just adding the indexes, rather than the value, so they don't work for positive number either. The grand total works because you are adding all the values properly, rather than adding the indexes. FYI,

```
for index in range(len(numbers)) :
```

does not give you the values, but rather : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6...(indexes) till the end of the range, to get the value numbers you would do

```
for value in numbers:
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. It is most helpful.